# Как вставить <script></script> через innerHtml в javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно вставить через innerHTML в js в нужный div через id два скрипта вида `<script>...</script><script>...</script>`. Можно ли их как нибудь вынести в файлы? Если можно, то подскажите пожалуйста как? И как их вывести через innerHTML?
Заранее спаибо!

Comment: вообще ничего непонятно что хотите и что не получается. Если хотите вставить через `InnerHTML` - таки вставляйте через него

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете добавить тег `script` через `innerHTML`, так как [стандарт запрещает выполнение подобных скриптов](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) в целях безопасности. Используйте более стандартные способы, которые описаны в интернете, к примеру:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src','http://example.com/site.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score -2):

Думаю, удобней было бы использовать jquery. 
А так, вот [тут](http://innerhtml.ru) можно посмотреть, пару полезных приёмов для этого свойства.